# php simple xml child nod number plus

Tags: php, simplexml

I want use php simple xml parse some tree like this.

how to plus all the `tree->item->object->num`?

I want get an int `16` (`2 + 4 + 7 + 2 + 1`)

> ```
> <tree>
>   <item>
>     <object>
>       <num>2</num>
>     </object>
>     <object>
>       <num>4</num>
>     </object>
>   </item>
>   <item>
>     <object>
>       <num>7</num>
>     </object>
>     <object>
>       <num>2</num>
>     </object>
>   </item>
>   <item>
>     <object>
>       <num>1</num>
>     </object>
>   </item>
> </tree>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple/ugly version:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($your_xml);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nums = $xp->query('//num');
$sum = 0;
foreach($nums as $num) {
   $sum += $num->nodeValue;
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($yourXMLString);

$acc = 0;
foreach($xml->item as $item)
{
    foreach($item->object as $object)
    {
        $acc += $object->num;
    }
}

echo $acc; // 16
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tree = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$nums = $tree->xpath('/tree/item/object/num');

// Array functions to sum the numbers
$sum = array_sum(array_map('intval', $nums));

// or, Loop to sum the number
$sum = 0;
foreach ($nums as $num) {
    $sum += $num;
}
```